# Integrated touchpose

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector

I found about "Touchpose" from https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose and i tried to integrate to my code,but when i run the project, i got this error message : **[UIApplication setAlwaysShowTouches:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d1c0f0**

I am using storyboard, what is my mistake?
Or do you know any tutorials like "TouchPose"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the README on the Github page, it has the solution!

**Quote from the GitHub README:**

To use Touchposé with an app, indicate that QTouchposeApplication should be used instead of UIApplication. This is done by specifying the application class in UIApplicationMain:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv,
                                 NSStringFromClass([QTouchposeApplication class]),
                                 NSStringFromClass([QAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

That’s it; no other steps are needed. By default, touch events are only displayed when actually connected to an external device. If you want to always show touch events, set the alwaysShowTouches property of QTouchposeApplication to YES.

Comment: Ahhh... Thanks a lot, i couldn't understand when i read the this part in first time because of my english :). I understood now,Thanks again...